# Can a song's chords be interpreted in many different ways?

Tags: chords, ear-training

From one of the songs I am trying to interpret, I am confused about which base chord is the right base chord. From the song, around the `00:59` part of the song(Where the chorus starts), I thought the chord was  `G` when I tried matching it with the notes on my fretboard(the guitar doesn't really have `Eb` to check and I only play guitar sadly). However, when I tried the `Eb` chord from [the online virtual piano](https://www.musicca.com/piano), `Eb` also sounded great to me as a bass note. And it turns out the `Eb` was the right chord but I can't still convince myself that the `G` chord is not the base note.
Is this just the problem of my ears or is it because a song can have multiple chords for the same part?

Song:  [Olivia Rodrigo- Driver's license](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Bjf-iExroI)

Comment: It sounds like an Ebmaj7 that resolves to a Bb. Chords can often be interpreted in different ways, but I don't think that is the issue. I don't hear a G chord here.

Comment: Hmm, I tried humming it and I always hum the Second octave G. Am I just getting confused with the melody? Oh, and by different interpreted chord, do you mean inversion or can the base actually be different?

Comment: The fact that you can hum a G note to a chord and it sounds good does not mean that the chord being played is G. You could hum a G note to many chords and it would sound OK if the note is part of the chord. As for your second question, perhaps this is relevant: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/73795/term-for-two-differently-named-chords-that-contain-the-same-notes

Comment: "Base" or "bass"?

Comment: A `G` _major_ chord? I would not expect that to sound similar to `Eb` major. The would be a `B` natural, `Bb` cross relationship. `G` minor - with its `Bb` third could sound similar to `Eb` major.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but do you know how to play barre chords yet?

Answer (score 3):

The chord in the song at that point is an Ebmaj7, which has the notes Eb G Bb D so there is a G note in there but it is not a G chord. The lowest note played by the piano arpeggios is a G but the bass plays an Eb below it.

One thing that struck me is you mentioned this:

“...the guitar doesn't really have Eb to check...”

Guitar is a chromatic instrument and can play any chord. Maybe you meant there is no open chord like G, E, D etc. to check it with. You can play Ebmaj7 fairly simply on guitar like this:  x-x-1-3-3-3. If you are unfamiliar with this it is the 6 strings from low to high and what fret to play on each string. The X’s mean don’t play that string. You can also capo the first fret and play a x-x-0-2-2-2, it’s the same chord.

Comment: Oh! then I guess I was stuck with the lowest G in piano! The bass notes aren't played with piano, right?

Comment: A piano can play bass notes but it is not in this case. The G played by the piano is just below middle C. There is another instrument playing the bass notes, possibly a synthesizer or organ and it is playing an Eb well below that.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in another answer. Be aware that the lowest note needn't be the root of the chord. If that chord is E♭, then the bass note could be any of E♭, G or B♭. Any of them could be the lowest note played. If you thought the bass note was G (and if it actually was), then that doesn't make the chord automatically G. It is likeely that at that point, the chord is E♭, with a G bass - making it 1st inversion (again something mentioned in another answer).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Inversion really tricks me up haha